# No Back Button is found on Worklight Console

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mbs

My understanding is that the Worklight console provides a web component simulator for mobile application to be run but I see that it is missing the Android back button on its screen.

My question is: Where can I find the back button on IBM Worklight console for android?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Worklight Console's Mobile Browser Simulator is meant to only preview the *web resources* of your Hybrid application.

There is no Back button available in this context. To test the Back button functionality,  preview your Android application in the Android Emulator or a physical device.

Comment: @SureshSharma, If my answer helped you solve this issue, please mark as answered.